# Here Maps Premium SDK works on Android Auto?

Tags: android, kotlin, here-api, heremaps-android-sdk, here-android

HERE-maps premium sdk works with Android Auto sdk? I`m developing a feature just to mirror my maps in car but always get the same error:

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
    at com.here.android.mpa.mapping.AndroidXMapFragment.onCreateView(AndroidXMapFragment.java:1)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2963)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:518)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2189)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2100)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2002)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3136)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchViewCreated(FragmentManager.java:3063)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:2988)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:546)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2189)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2100)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2002)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3136)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3070)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:251)
    at com.google.android.gms.car.h.onStart(CarFragmentActivity.java:67)
    at com.google.android.apps.auto.sdk.CarActivity.onStart(CarActivity.java:44)
    at com.google.android.gms.car.internal.CarActivityHostImpl.a(CarActivityHostImpl.java:551)
    at com.google.android.gms.car.internal.CarActivityHostImpl.a(CarActivityHostImpl.java:232)
    at com.google.android.gms.car.internal.CarActivityHostImpl.a(CarActivityHostImpl.java:783)
    at com.google.android.gms.car.internal.t.run(Unknown Source:2)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at com.google.android.gms.d.a.a.b.dispatchMessage(TracingHandler.java:9)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:235)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7441)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
W/System.err: HERE-SDK: HERE SDK Version: 3.14.2.192
```

Can anyone help me? Tks

Comment: The error message is too unspecific to point to anything Android Auto related. But yes, the Premium Edition should work with Android Auto. Also the new 4.x HERE SDK Editions, like Lite, Explore and Navigate Edition should work with Android Auto.

Comment: @Datasun, we are using version 3.14, do you know if this version is compatible?
The error is triggered when instantiating the AndroidXMapFragment () fragment: `val context = ApplicationContext(requireContext()).apply {.... } 
mapFragmentView.let { fragment ->

            fragment.init(context) { error -> ...... }}`
  
Error:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference

Comment: I would suspect that this error is not related to the HERE SDK. Maybe try to generate a plain Auto SDK example without the HERE SDK integrated. I am not an expert for the 3.x SDK, but 3.14 sounds quite new, so it should work.

Comment: HERE SDK needs to be adapted by the customer for use in Android Auto. Customer can use SDK to to be used in Android Auto but there is not integration support provided.